# Why zonal statistics as table does not include some of my bigger buffers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, zonal-statistics

I am using zonal statistics as table for calculating statistical parameters in different size disc  and I also use a raster layer(canopy cover) as input. I have reclassified NODATA as 0 value. 
I have used 780 points  for creating different size buffers (outside buffers) around these points. My buffers overlap but are not dissolved. Then I have used these buffers seperately and their FID and a raster layer as inputs of zonal statistics as table. Calculations are doing well for small buffers (r=50,100,200,500m), but the result tables just includes 766 rows for my 1000m buffer and 750 rows for my 2000m buffer. How I can solve the problem?

Comment: What are the precise steps that you have performed (all tools and parameter values)?  Where precisely did what you observed start to depart from what you expected from reading that tool's documentation?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Also, please provide precise tool names and parameter values.  The more that you can provide a recipe for how to see what you are saying, the more likely it is that a potential answerer will stop and answer rather than moving onto the next question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:
The problem is that zonal statistics as table does not support overlapping features. Fortunately,the Spatial Analyst Supplemental Tools, created by Esri, includes something called Zonal Statistics2 and this can be helpful in this case.